# MySQL calculate delta (difference) from previous upload day data for next 6 months

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to run a query which will:

- Calculate the "Δ" which is the different between the previous day report and the current, for example: 23 Nov, value is 10 and 22 Nov is 9, so Δ = +1, increased by one
- And do so on for all days up to 6 months from previous day

Data

```
date      value reportDate
1-8-2017    142   1-8-2017
2-8-2017     69   1-8-2017
3-8-2017     57   1-8-2017
4-8-2017     44   1-8-2017      

date      value reportDate
1-8-2017    136   2-8-2017
2-8-2017    139   2-8-2017
3-8-2017    104   2-8-2017
4-8-2017     66   2-8-2017
```

Required Result

```
Report Date: 2-8-2017   

date      value Delta
1-8-2017    136    -6
2-8-2017    139    70
3-8-2017    104    47
4-8-2017     66    22
```

I know I can calculate by running another query inside loop after getting rows for a date. But I want to calculate in a single query. Data is very large, millions of records and growing on daily basis.

I want to optimize the query as much as possible as it's bottleneck for the system and system gets stuck while running each query for each row. Basically I can't do anything while currently calculating by each row.

Comment: Do the historical values ever change?  If you can guarrentee that (say) there will be no changes more than 7 days old, then you can pre-calculate everything up to that date, then you are only calculating at the most, 7 days worth every day.

Comment: Yes historical values can be changed with custom values wherever is required

Comment: OK, why not create a normalisation table that contains just the deltas, then whenever any data (historical or not) gets changed, store the delta too, then your query can just use the delta table instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single query would be something like this. I hope there is an index on `date` and `reportDate` columns:

```sql
SET @date := '2017-08-02';

SELECT t1.date, t2.value, t2.value - t1.value AS delta
FROM test AS t1 
JOIN test AS t2 ON (t1.date = t2.date)
WHERE t2.reportDate = @date
AND t1.reportDate = DATE_SUB(@date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: yes `date` and `reportDate` are index and also `date-reportDate` as unique key to prevent duplicate values